# Automatically run goalseek when cell value changes by a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I need to run a goalseek every time the value of cell "E9" changes, cell E9 = Rand(), is there a way to do this? The goalseek and cell E9 are on different sheets. The VBA script I found online is as follows and it is not working. Once I hit F9, my Excel just keeps iterating and gives me "#NUM!" What am I missing here? My goalseek is related to cell E9. Cell 70 is a function of E9.

In Sheet1 I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

 Dim KeyCell As Range
 Set KeyCell = Range("E9")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCell, Range("E9")) _
Is Nothing Then

Backsolve

End If
End Sub
```

In Module1 I have:

```
Sub Backsolve()

Sheets("Backsolve").Select
Range("C70").Select
Range("C70").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C71")
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

Help please!

Comment: maybe try increasing the Maximum Iterations https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-NUM-error-f5193bfc-4400-43f4-88c4-8e1dcca0428b

Answer (score 0):

may be this will work:

In Sheet1:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
     Backsolve
End Sub
```

In Module1

```
Sub Backsolve()    
    Sheets("Backsolve").Range("C70").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C71")
End Sub
```